# How can I query whether an objectID is in an array in MongoDB with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is how my model looks like in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5951552c5bb94058b203d3e3"),
    "roleName" : "Bartender",
    "userList" : [ 
        ObjectId("5926ff5088a3da5bf0d3d43b")
    ],
    "deadline" : ISODate("2017-06-26T18:40:44.153Z"),
    "__v" : 1
}
```

I would like to query 2 things together. 
1, -Show me the model of the "role" I'm looking for.
2, -Give me true or false depending on whether the user's ID is to be found in the userList array.

```
 exports.roleView = function(req,res, next){
    const userID = req.params.userId;
    const roleID = req.params.roleId;


      const findUser = Role.findById({ _id: roleID
      }).populate('userList', 'userName')
      .then((result)=>{return result})
      .catch((err)=>{return err});


      const userinRole = Role.findOne({
      _id:roleID, userList: userID})
      .then((result)=>{return true})
      .catch((err)=>{return false});

      return Promise.all([findUser, userinRole])
            .then((role)=>{
            res.json(role);
                  });
                };
```

Yet, every time don't have a match in userinRole, Mongo would just simply freeze without response.
Is it actually the proper way, or would you approach it differently? Thank you so much!

Comment: if you have the userID already then why not simply `(result.userList.indexOf(useriD) != -1)`. You don't need another query to do that. Alternately just filter in the initial query as `.findOne({ "_id": roleID, "userList": userID })` if your intent was to not return anything if the user does not have that role.

Comment: I saw this indexOf and tried, but never really worked out. I just don't know how it works. Would you put it exactly? IF statement? - Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a logical comparison. `.indexOf()` returns the "index" of the array where the element was found or `-1` where it is not found. So comparing to `-1` returns `true/false`. Pretty basic language stuff really.